# How to get image src url in source code with xpath in python

Tags: python, html, xpath, beautifulsoup, lxml

So, i'm developing a program to download some images from sites, and i have to somehow get the "src" part of the img tag.
I was able to do this with selenium, but i had to adapt the code and now i'm using BeautifulSoup4 and lxml.
I currently have the whole source code of the page (site) in a variable "mystr", and i wanted to give an xpath and find that xpath inside that variable? Is it possible? (probably)
The reason i'm posting this question is because i can't seem to parse the variable to lxml and use it's function .xpath()

--READ FOR MORE CONTEXT OF THE PROBLEM--
I'm reading some data from an excel file (reference values and url's), i want to open the url, download the product image, and rename it for it's reference.
I can do this with multiple images, but when the url only has 1 image, i wanted to go with the xpath to download the image and i didn't want to use selenium again.

Thanks in advance.
I think this is the part of the code that matters for this question.

```
try: #Extrair o html
    fp = urllib.request.urlopen(links[i])
    mybytes = fp.read()
    mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
    fp.close()
except Exception as ex: #Exceção do html
    print("Não foi possivel extrair o HTML deste url")
    erros.append(i)
    continue                
try: #Passar para Beautiful soup 4
    soup = BeautifulSoup(mystr, "lxml")
    #print(mystr, file = open("teste.txt", "a"))
except Exception as ex: # Exceção do Beautiful soup 4
    print("Não foi possivel converter o HTML para bs4\n\n" + ex)
    erros.append(i)
    continue
try: #Navegar até ao DIV dentro do html extraido
    main_div = soup.find_all("div", {"id": div_id})
    if len(main_div) == 0:
        parser = etree.HTMLParser()
        tree = etree.parse(mybytes, parser)
        #print(tree, file=open("tree.txt", "a"))
        #image = tree.xpath('//*[@id="image"]')
        image = tree.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a/img")
        print(image[0].tag)
        #input("--------------------------------------------------")
except Exception as ex: #Exceção se não existir um div dentro do HTML extraido com o ID fornecido
    print("Não existe nenhum DIV com o id fornecidon\n\n" + ex)
    erros.append(i)
    continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `BeautifulSoup` way:

```
img_src=soup.find("img")["src"]
```

One `lxml etree` way:

```
img_src=tree.xpath('//img')[0].attrib.get('src')
```

Comment: I'm getting this error! `can only concatenate str (not "OSError") to str` 
Any idea what it can be?

Comment: Try reading your tree as `tree = etree.parse(StringIO(mybytes), parser)`. `StringIO` comes from this import: `from io import StringIO`.

Comment: Now i'm getting this one `can only concatenate str (not "TypeError") to str`

Comment: On which line are you getting that?

Comment: it's because of this line `tree = etree.parse(StringIO(mybytes), parser)`

Comment: Replace mybytes with mystr.

Comment: Thank you so so so much, i was stuck with this for over 4 hours, and i apparently was only missing the StringIO() part, once again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For an start with xpath have a look to http: wiki/XPath or for more information to USING XPATHS.
//a/@href' selects the href attribute from all links ( tags).
For all image src attributes this will be //img/@src.

Comment: Please add the correct format to your links and code shown. If would be better if you could add your suggestion directly into the code that was post by Gustavo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import urllib.request

try:
    fp = urllib.request.urlopen(links[i])
    mybytes = fp.read()
    mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
    fp.close()
except Exception as ex:
    print("Não foi possível extrair o HTML deste URL")
    erros.append(i)
    continue

try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(mystr, "html.parser")  # Use "html.parser" instead of "lxml"
except Exception as ex:
    print("Não foi possível converter o HTML para bs4\n\n" + str(ex))
    erros.append(i)
    continue

try:
    # Find all image elements using BeautifulSoup
    img_elements = soup.find_all("img")

    if img_elements:
        # Extract image URLs using BeautifulSoup
        image_urls = [img["src"] for img in img_elements]
        for url in image_urls:
            print(url)
    else:
        # If no image elements were found, try using lxml's etree
        parser = etree.HTMLParser()
        tree = etree.fromstring(mystr, parser)
        image = tree.xpath('/html/body//img/@src')
        
        if image:
            for url in image:
                print(url)
        else:
            print("No image URLs found.")
except Exception as ex:
    print("Erro ao extrair URLs de imagens:\n" + str(ex))
    erros.append(i)
    continue
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).